# VB.Net Dropdownlist Value is always 1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I got a Dropdownlist filled from a Database, using the ID from the Database as ValueField but it just doesn't work

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim strConnection As String = "DEMOString"
    connection = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
    connection.ConnectionString = strConnection
    connection.Open()

    Dim dtb As DataTable

    Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM Personen"
    dtb = New DataTable()
    Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, connection)
        dad.Fill(dtb)
    End Using

    dtb.Columns.Add("Fullname", GetType(String), "Vorname + ' ' + Nachname")
    ddlName.Items.Clear()
    ddlName.DataSource = dtb
    ddlName.DataTextField = "Fullname"
    ddlName.DataValueField = "sozNr"
    ddlName.DataBind()

    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

When I try using ddlName.SelectedItem.Value later i get 1 for every Item.

The Using Code

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dateString As String = tbDate.Text
    Dim name As String = ddlName.SelectedItem.Text
    Dim des As String = tbDescription.Text
    MsgBox(ddlName.SelectedItem.Value)
```

Comment: Side-note: Instead of the relative expensive methods `DataTable.Clear` + `Columns.Clear` simply use `dtb = new DataTable()`. Have you debugged, what is in the table after `Fill`?

Comment: Why do you use websites at all then? Use a web application to avoid such issues or find out how to debug a website. You can't develop without a debugger.

Comment: So I debugged now, just found out how this properly workes. The table is what I want it to be. In it are all the entries which are in my Database too

Comment: does it work if you use the table as datasource instead of the dataview? So `ddlName.DataSource = dtb`. Btw, i don't see where the table is declared. Declare it in this method and not outside or in session.

Comment: It doesn't work with ddlName.DataSource=dtb either . and the table is declared in the class as Public Shared dtb As DataTable = New DataTable()

Comment: Never use `shared` fields in ASP.NET (even less public).  This will be used by every requests(user) and can cause multi-threading issues. Instead declare and initialize the `DataTable` in this method.

Comment: Yeah thats nice to know thanks but it still doesn't solve the Value problem

Comment: That's a different place. You have to show the method where you access the `ddlName.SelectedItem.Value` later. You should also show `Page_Load`, do you always databind the DropDownList or only `If Not Page.IsPostBack` as it is correct?

Comment: added all relevant code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to DataBind the `DropDownList` on every postback if viewstate is enabled(default). That will overwrite all changes like the `SelectedIndex`. Instead put the code in `Page_Load` in a `Not Is PostBack` check:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim strConnection As String = "DEMOString"
        connection = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
        connection.ConnectionString = strConnection
        connection.Open()

        Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM Personen"
        Dim dtb As New DataTable()
        Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, connection)
            dad.Fill(dtb)
        End Using

        dtb.Columns.Add("Fullname", GetType(String), "Vorname + ' ' + Nachname")
        ddlName.DataSource = dtb
        ddlName.DataTextField = "Fullname"
        ddlName.DataValueField = "sozNr"
        ddlName.DataBind()

        connection.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Side-Note: you should also not reuse the connection. Instead create, initialize and close it in the method where you use it, best by using the `Using`-statement which also ensures that it get's disposed/closed in case of an error.

Comment: It works thanks to the If Not Page.IsPostBack. and thanks to you ofc :D I really appreciate that you put so much time in my question!